# Validation accuracy on MNIST differs when training data in one go vs when separated

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

I have a 27G dataset to analyse, and because of the size of my RAM I can't feed all my data into my Neural Network at once, and I have to import bits of it, learn on them, and then another part, so the process would look some thing like this:

1. import 10% of data
2. learn
3. save model
4. delete the data on RAM
5. import the next 10% and so on

To see how this would affect a known dataset, I tested it on MNIST. the following is the process/procedure:

```
for 35 times:
  import 1/5 of the data
  learn 
  delete
  import the next 1/5
  learn
  delete
  ...
```

This is the code to import the dataset from tensorflow:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
(sep, label), (sep_t, label_t) = mnist.load_data()
```

Then, the network:

```
Dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense
fc_model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
      tf.keras.Input(shape=(28,28)),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      Dense(128, activation='relu'),
      Dense(32, activation='relu'),
      Dense(10, activation='softmax')])
fc_model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Below is the code for partially importing and learning the MNIST data set:

```
for k in range(35):
    for j in range(5):
        if i == 0:
            history = fc_model.fit(sep[i*12000:(i+1)*12000-1], label[i*12000:(i+1)*12000-1], batch_size=128, validation_data=(sep_t, label_t) ,epochs=1)
            fc_model.save('Mytf.h5')
            i = i + 1
        else:
            fc_model = load_model('Mytf.h5')
            history = fc_model.fit(sep[i*12000:(i+1)*12000-1], label[i*12000:(i+1)*12000-1], batch_size=128, validation_data=(sep_t, label_t) ,epochs=1)
            fc_model.save('Mytf.h5')
        valacc.append(history.history['val_accuracy'])
    valacc_epc.append(history.history['val_accuracy'])
```

The following is the code to learn the data in one whole dataset:

```
history_new = fc_model.fit(sep, label, batch_size=128, validation_data=(sep_t, label_t) ,epochs=35)
```

and the graph below is the comparison between the two methods in terms of accuracy of the validation data:

[image]

even though the difference is like 1% (96(avg)-95(avg)=1%), would this mean that when testing on a different dataset using the same methodology of saving and learning, this would result in reduced accuracy? is it better to do some investment and do it on a cloud computation platform?

Comment: This is what data generators are for. There's some weird effects that could happen with your solution, particularly as to how batches are organized and whether some training data is seen more than others.

Comment: @runDOSrun so what method is out there to learn on large datasets, with limited RAM?

Answer (score 0):

For both approaches, the batches are organized differently, so there would have to be some deviations (similar to shuffling the data vs feeding it in a specific order). But we can assume that these differences would not be consistent unless we observe this on a large amount of trials.

In any case, this is the common approach to loading large datasets bit by bit: tf.keras allows you to pass a Python generator for `model.fit(x)` (in case you want to research tutorials or work with an older API: until recently this was a separate method called `model.fit_generator`, [see API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)).

All the data generator needs to do is yield a batch of training data and labels `(x,y)` each time it is called. The API will take care of calling it for you, as long as you pass it with `fit`. The result is that everything is read batch-by-batch into the RAM. A very basic template for a generator is something like this ([source](https://medium.com/@fromtheast/implement-fit-generator-in-keras-61aa2786ce98)):

```
def generator(features, labels, batch_size):
    # Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels#
    batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, 64, 64, 3))
    batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size,1))

    while True:
       for i in range(batch_size):
           # choose random index in features
           index= random.choice(len(features),1)
           batch_features[i] = some_processing(features[index])
           batch_labels[i] = labels[index]
       yield batch_features, batch_labels
```